# Display metadata associated with annotations with PDF and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

Long time programmer, new to PDFs.

I'd like to create a web tool that is centered around a PDF. The PDF is a book with footnotes, and each footnote has an ID invisible to the reader. I'd like to allow users to add view the PDF, select a footnote and see metadata I have on the footnote to the left or right side of the PDF. I would use the ID of the footnote (embedded as an annotation in the PDF) to make an AJAX call to retrieve the metadata.

Which javascript library could I use to pull this off and how do I allow the displayed metadata scroll when the user scrolls the PDF?

Comment: Your question is not a good match for Stackoverflow, where recommendations of tools/software are discouraged. What you need to do has to be compatible with at least Adobe Reader, so your best bet would be Acrobat Professional.

Comment: You can't control the PDF experience without controlling the PDF viewer. Are you in a position to require that a particular PDF viewer be used? Is it acceptable for the PDF to be viewed in a browser?